# Labview LeCroy LT264 Lightning Impulse Test Signal Loss

Tags: labview

I use Lecroy LT264 oscilloscope to trace lightning impulse test (1.2/50usec waveform). I have driver for labview and use edge triggered example. One impulse is not shown in every three impulse. What could be the reason ? Thanks for your interest.

[image]

[image]

Also you can download code here : http://forums.ni.com/t5/Instrument-Control-GPIB-Serial/LeCroy-LT264-Lightning-Impulse-Test-Signal-Loss/td-p/2510994

Comment: Just a code comment, if you add all the front panel controls into a cluster (I'd also recommend making it a typedef) you can breakout the value you need from the cluster when it is needed and really clean up the block diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solve the problem. The reason is trigger level. I had set 40 V or 80 V. However when I set trigger level 150V, program shows all impulse.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see how many samples you are recording.  If the time it takes to collect samples is larger than the time spacing of the the trigger, then the hardware won't reset until all the samples are collected.  This means the trigger won't get rearmed.

Try reducing the number of samples collected if you need to trigger on every impulse.

Also, seeing your code might help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I add diagrams' photos. Which option should I change ? How can I configure time spacing of trigger or number of samples ?